# Ruby on rails indentation

Tags: indentation

It's possibly a stupid question, but I need some help as I can't find answer.

I indent some code in ROR, then later I deleted the upper layer and wanted to move that back, but i can't find the shortcut as it's quite a lot of lines of code...

example:
originally

```
if abc
  if def
    some code
    some code
   end
end
```

but now

```
if def
  some code
  some code
end
```

Comment: I am using cloud9 ide

Comment: why did someone down vote this post without leaving any comment!?

Comment: The question shouldn't even be here. That alone is a reason for down voting it. This has nothing to do with ROR, but is about your environment, which you didn't even care to specify in the question.

Comment: That's not true - The reason being is that ROR IDE might have a specific short cut for doing it. Just like Excel has different short cut on Mac and Window. I plead you to cancel your down vote because I would need the reputation to comment.

Comment: I removed it. But next time just try looking at the very obviously located documentation: https://docs.c9.io/docs/keybindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the text to outdent and press Shift-Tab

Info from keybindings page of the documentation: https://docs.c9.io/docs/keybindings